# Copy a partial row of data from one sheet to a new sheet within the same workbook based on cell content

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have scoured the web for a solution to this challenge that I am having, but have not found a suitable solution.  I have decent with formulas, but have no experience in VBA or other programming within Excel.  I am hoping that one of the many Excel gurus can help me solve this challenge.

Sample Sheet
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95272767/Sample%20Sheet.xlsx

The rows of data always begin in row 4 and can extend down to row 1000.

I have a sheet of data (Linked Above) that was produced by underlying formulas.  My goal is to copy partial rows of data based on the content of column F of the same row, while leaving both the formula and original data intact. Rows above 4 and column O need to remain on the original sheet.

For example...

Row 4 has in column F, ab1.  The following cells A4 through N4 need to be copied to sheet labeled Client 1.

Row 5 has in column F, ab1.  The following cells A5 through N5 need to be copied to sheet labeled Client 1.

Row 5 has in column F, ab2.  The following cells A6 through N6 need to be copied to sheet labeled Client 2.

This process continues through to the end of the data.

Thanks so much in advance for any assistance that can be provided.

Cheers
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. I have tried to comment it pretty thoroughly so as to explain what is happening in the macro:

```
Sub CopySomeCells()
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet 'destination for the copied cells'
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet 'source of data worksheet'
Dim rng As Range 'range variable for all data'
Dim rngToCopy As Range 'range to copy'
Dim r As Long 'row counter'
Dim x As Long 'row finder'
Dim clientCode As String
Dim clientSheet As String

Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") '## The source data worksheet, modify as needed ##
    With sourceSheet
        '## the sheet may have data between rows 4 and 1000, modify as needed ##'
        Set rng = .Range("A4", Range("A1000").End(xlUp))

        '## iterate over the rows in the range we defined above ##'
        For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count


            '## Set the range to copy ##'
            Set rngToCopy = Range(rng.Cells(r, 1), rng.Cells(r, 12))

            '## ignore rows that don't have a value in column F ##
            If Not rng.Cells(r, 6).Value = vbNullString Then

                '## Set the targetSheet dynamically, based on the code in column F ##'
                '  e.g., "ab1" --> Client 1, "ab2" --> Client 2, etc. '
                '## Set the client code ##"
                clientCode = rng.Cells(r, 6).Value

                '## determine what sheet to use ##'
                ' I do this by finding the client code in the lookup table, which
                ' is in range "O24:O37", using the MATCH function.
                ' Then, offset it -1 rows (the row above) which will tell us "Client Code 1", etc.

                clientSheet = .Range("O23").Offset( _
                    Application.Match(clientCode, .Range("O24:O37"), False), 0).Offset(-1, 0).Value
                ' take that value "Client Code 1" and replace "Code " with nothing, so that
                ' will then give us the sheet name, e.g., "Client Code 1" --> "Client 1", etc. ##'
                clientSheet = Replace(clientSheet, "Code ", vbNullString)

                Set targetSheet = Worksheets(clientSheet)

                '## Find the next empty row in this worksheet ##'
                x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1

                '## Copy the selected sub-range, ##'

                rngToCopy.Copy 

                '## Paste values only to the target sheet ##'
                targetSheet.Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            End If

        Next '## proceed to process the next row in this range ##'

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer and for the detailed comments.  There is one thing that I didn't clarify.  The client code is based on variables like peoples initials and could have a number if there are more than one with the same initials. `code` '## Set the targetSheet dynamically, based on the digit in column F ##'
                '  e.g., "ab1" --> Client 1, "ab2" --> Client 2, etc. '
                Set targetSheet = Worksheets("Client " & _
                    Replace(rng.Cells(r, 6).Value, "ab", vbNullString)) `code`

Comment: It appears that I have messed up the previous reply...  Sorry.  :)  To continue my though, I was planning on having the five client sheets pre-built as client 1, client 2, ect.  What needs to change with the line of script that references the dynamically created sheets?  The client codes on the right of the sheet are the user entered client codes that will be searched for in creating the sample sheet that I attached.  Thanks Scott

Comment: I have also discovered through testing that the data is written starting at row one of each client sheet.  Is there a way to have row written beginning with row 4 of each of the client pages?  This way I can add the same headers and what not like on sheet 1.  Thanks again for your help.  The code that was give originally works exactly how I previously described in my original question.  Scott

Comment: change `x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1` to say `x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A")) + 4` and that should start at row 4 in each Client worksheet.

Comment: Also, if this has helped resolve your problem, please consider marking the answer as "accepted".  Cheers!

Comment: So far thing are working great!  I will definatly accept the answer.  Is it possible to rectify the '## Set the targetSheet dynamically, based on the digit in column F e.g., "ab1" --> Client 1, "ab2" --> Client 2, etc. ' ?  Is there a way to copy the rows without referencing the  ab or 1,2,3,4,5 in the sample client code?  They will not usually be there to reference in that form.  As mentioned in an earlier comment, the code is based typically on a persons initials.  thanks again Scott

Comment: in order to change it I would need to know more about what will exist in column F, and how those values would correspond to a particular worksheet. Will the worksheet names correspond with the values in column F somehow (e.g., "DZ" --> Sheet("DZ"), "AB" --> Sheet("AB"), etc.)?

Comment: I have updated the sample sheet https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95272767/Copy%20of%20Sample%20Sheet%20test%202.xlsm to include the underlying formula for column F.  The calculated sheet in the sample is sheet 4 in the real workbook.  There is raw data export that is laid on sheet 1 and is processed through sheet 2 and sheet 3 to the calculated fees (sheet 4).  On the calculated fee sheet, the user declares what the what the client codes are to be parsed.  This is entered in the box on the right under the labels client 1, client 2, etc.  They are extracted from column G  Thanks again Scott.

Comment: Formula is not relevant, what matters is the `value` of those cells, and how those relate/correspond to one of the `Client #` worksheets. What sort of **values** will be on column F, and how would you logically assign those to different client worksheets?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry about that.  I have found that they are always 2 letters and one number.  Real examples are rc1 / rj1 / af2 / mk1 / vv2 / ck1.  There is one exception, kfp1.  That can change if it creates a huge problem.  As the formula references client 1 code in cell O25, client 2 in cell O28, and so on, I think that we can anchor the script by what is input in those cells, yes?  The sheets for the clients will always be there as Client 1, Client 2, etc.   Thanks Scott

Comment: so does "rc1" go to "Client 1"? And "kfp2" would go to "Client 2"?

Comment: What goes into the client list box on the right will change with each run of the report.  This is manually input by the person running the report.  Each week the clients change, so the client code do as well.  I was thinking that whatever is in assigned in the client box would directly tie to the client tab.  Thanks Scott

Comment: Well I don't see any listbox in this file. In any case, yes, you're on the right idea. As long as you can describe what circumstances dictate that client "XYZ" should land on "Client 1" worksheet, etc., then it can be modified accordingly. But, without knowing how or what data you might have, this is not really something I can do at the moment. For example, if "David Zemens" was a client, which Client sheet would my data end up on, and why???

Comment: The client box I am referring to is between cell O24 and O37 on the .  The 5 client codes are filled in by the sheet user.  They know that they have been working with 5 clients this week and thus the data dump will contain those clients. The clients are Sally Sue (SS1), Joe Smith (JS1), Jack Black (JB1), Betty Gable (BG1), and Clark Kent (CK1).  The users manually input those client codes into the client code area.  There is no specific order to it other than I have labeled the data as such.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95272767/Copy%20of%20Sample%20Sheet%20test%202.xlsm

Comment: Is it *always* going to be in that range of cells? And will there *always* be 5 clients or sometimes will there be more (or fewer)?

Comment: Ran out of space, see previous note.  In the client box, Client 1 code goes to client 1 sheet, Client 2 code goes to Client 2 sheet, etc.  This range of cells will always be there, but there could be any number of clients from 1 to 5.

Comment: OK I think the revision above will do it. I have not tested it though.

Comment: see revision above. I have not had a chance to test it and will not until very late tonight. I notice that, although I did solve the immediate problem as presented in your original question, that you still have not marked this answer as accepted... kindly consider doing so.

Comment: Browser didn't update.  Let me try the newer code.  I will mark it now.  I thought it would close the thread.

Comment: I have marked the answer as accepted, sorry about that.  I have also tested the code and it states "subscript out of range."  Thanks for working on this and testing late tonight is fine. - Scott

Comment: subscript out of range because I didn't have a chance to test it out, just shooting from the hip :)  try now.

Comment: That seems to be working!  One question, Column F is showing Zeros on the client pages. BTW, your "shootin from the hip" was way closer than my days of trying to figure out how to do what you have done.  :)

Comment: I stand corrected, the columns are jumbled up.  Column F is in column A.  The sales Date is completely missing from the client sheets.  Column M and N are missing as well.

Comment: I was able to add the missing columns M and N by changing the 14 to 16.  :)

Comment: Good for figuring that out!  For the Column F/A mismatch, change `targetSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = ... ` to `targetSheet.Cells(x, 6).Value`  the `.Cells(#, #)` designates a cell by it's row/column, so we need to put the value in to column , not column 1. Sorry!

Comment: No worries, I was just working through that.  :)  I have moved the code to my real sheet and found that I have to add one of those lines for each of the columns as all my cells that are copied have formulas.  There is likely a way to combine my 14 lines into one line.  On my real sheet, it only processes one line at a time and all lines are copied to client sheet 1.  I am trying to work through that now.

Comment: There is a way, using the `PasteSpecial` method (which allows you to paste values only).  Use the code as revised :)

Comment: I am so sorry that this has tuned into a big pain.  I hope that there is a way that I can repay you for your extreme helpfulness!  That worked in respect to only copying the values, but it left the copy outline "marching ants" around the row that was copied.  I am also challenged with getting the script to parse all of the data on my real sheet.  It only looks at the first row only.  Scott

Comment: I have tested and retested my real excel file and it will only parse 1 row of data.  The same code except for changing the sheet name in `Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")` works.  I am not sure where to look from here, I am at a loss.  :)  Thanks for any furhter help that you can offer. - Scott

Comment: You realize the "marching ants" will disappear as soon as you double-click to another selection, it's not like, something permanent in the file...

Comment: On the example file this parses all your rows correctly (3 rows to Client 1, 2 rows to Client 2, and 1 row each to clients 3, 4 and 5). There must be something different about your real excel file which is causing different behavior. But I can't imagine what that might be without seeing the file.

Comment: No worries on the marching ants.  :)  It was just different than previously.  Is there a way that I can get you the file? I also feel that I owe you something for all your time and help.

Comment: you could upload the file to Google Docs or email it to me at dzemens at gmail.