# Copying data based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit stuck and hoping to find some help. I have some experience in VBA but this particular problem exceeds my programming knowledge.

I have a sheet with 1000 - 1250 rows of data, and anywhere from 20 - 60 columns that can change monthly.

What I am hoping to do is look at each cell for an X, and when found it will create a new line on a separate tab. The line would contain the first cell in the row where the X was found and the column header from the column the X was found in.

I have been able to write some things that will find the X's in the sheet, create new items on another page and the like, but I can't get one script to do everything I need.

This is an example of the data structure:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kKnF.jpg)

Expected result:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHca7.jpg)

Sorry for the links, I am too new to post photos.

Any help on how this can be achieved, documents, tips or the like would be super helpful and most appreciated. Thank you for looking!

Andrew

EDIT:

Some of the code I have put together:

```
Dim uSht As String
Dim wsExists As Boolean
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet



Sub CopyData()

'Setup Sheetnames
uSht = "UPLOAD"
uTem = "TEMPLATE"

' Stop flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Check for Upload Worksheet
WorksheetExists (uSht)

'MsgBox (wsExists)
If wsExists = False Then
' If it does not exist, create it
Call CreateSheet("UPLOAD")
End If

'Setup stuff
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(uTem)
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(uSht)

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'MsgBox (lRow)
'MsgBox (lCol)

Range(Cells(lRow, lColumn)).Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub CreateSheet(wsName)
'Creates the uSht worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = uSht
End With
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(wsName As String) As Boolean
'Check to see if uSht exists and return.
wsName = UCase(wsName)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If UCase(ws.Name) = wsName Then
        wsExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
WorksheetExists = wsExists
End Function
```

Comment: Just X alone in the cell?  Multiple X per line, or only one per line?

Comment: You state that you've written some code but I see no code. [Edit] your question to include the code you've written.

Comment: Just one X alone in the cell indicating a project applies to a location.

Comment: Sorry, also, the code I have is all separate functions with the intent of learning how to search for values in the data, return row data when a value is found and the like, I was unable to get one function to do all the work so there is not much to post?

Comment: I do appreciate the help, I get basic concepts of how this works, but am stuck on the complexities of combining code to do the proper work.

Comment: Editing the main post to reflect code better...

Comment: Please reread my comment above and attempt to follow the directive requested.

Comment: Also, Mr Williams, there is only one X in a cell per column, but not row. Meaning one location (row) can have multiple projects (column.) Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Using `FindAll` from here: [Extracting specific cells from multiple Excel files and compile it into one Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651346/extracting-specific-cells-from-multiple-excel-files-and-compile-it-into-one-exce/50651559#50651559)
(but change `LookAt:=xlPart` to `LookAt:=xlWhole`)

Rough outline:

```
Dim col, c, dest As Range

Set dest = sheets("results").Range("A2")
Set col = FindAll(sheets("data").range("a1").currentregion, "X")

For each c in col
    dest.resize(1,2).value = array(c.entirerow.cells(1).value, _
                                   c.entirecolumn.cells(1).value)
    set dest = dest.offset(1, 0)
next
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am digesting the responses. I really do appreciate your time, thank you Jeeped and Tim!

Comment: Also reviewing this, which is helping as well!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453447/copy-a-partial-row-of-data-from-one-sheet-to-a-new-sheet-within-the-same-workboo?rq=1

Comment: Thank you again, Jeeped's solution worked perfectly.

Also, I am learning more about VBA with your help and examples. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need a Find/FindNext loop that will locate all X values in the first worksheet. After a found cell is located, the cell's row and column can be used to identify the location and project.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim addr As String, loc As String, pro As String
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, fnd As Range

    Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set fnd = .Cells.Find(What:="x", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            addr = fnd.Address(0, 0)
            Do
                loc = .Cells(fnd.Row, "A").Value
                pro = .Cells(1, fnd.Column).Value
                With ws2
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = loc
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = pro
                End With
                Set fnd = .Cells.FindNext(after:=fnd)
            Loop Until addr = fnd.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```